# Controllability: Rank VS Determinant

Tags: simulations, linear-systems

Assume that we have our state space model:

$$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$$

I have a system $A$ and signalmatrix $B$ and if I do in MATLAB:

```
>> rank(ctrb(A, B))
```

I get rank of the controllability matrix.

But if I do this in MATLAB:

```
>> det(ctrb(A, B))
```

I can get none zero number. That means that the system is controllable.

But who is best method to use? Determine if the system is controllable by using the criteria

```
>> det(ctrb(A, B)) =/= 0
```

or

```
rank(ctrb(A, B)) = n
```

where $n$ is the lenght of the state vector or the dimension of $A$.

Comment: You should point out you are using Matlab: not everybody may understand your notations

Comment: What is `ctrb`?

Comment: A Matlab and Octave function of controllability for a state space model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the controllability matrix

$$C=\begin{pmatrix}B &AB &A^2B &\cdots &A^{n-1}B\end{pmatrix}$$

is not square: A is $n\times n$ whereas $B$ is $n\times m$, resulting in $C$ being $n\times mn$, so its determinant does not exist. The most general criterion is therefore on the rank. However, if $B$ has only one column, then $\det C$ exists. However, the computation of a determinant may not be numerically stable when the matrix is singular or nearly singular. By that I mean that floating-point round-offs may give you a small but non-zero determinant even though the rank is less than $n$, and the determinant should therefore be zero. On the contrary, almost every algorithm to compute the rank I know of is numerically stable (this is the case in Matlab iirc). So even if $B$ has only one column, I would recommend using the rank.

Comment: But I have a book about optimal control which uses the determinant.

Comment: If B has only one column, then the control matrix is square. In that case, the determinant makes sense. What are the size of the matrices in your example?

Comment: The A matrix is 6x6 and B matrix is 6x1. The problem is that I got a nonzero value of det(ctrb(A, B)). I get 0.002. And rank 2 if I use rank(ctrb(A, B)).

Comment: I have updated my answer to answer your question, I hope.

Comment: Okej! I got rank = 2, even if the state vector is 6. That means that my system, is not OK for state feedback reguator. But how is that possible? I mean....I can simulate that system and give it an input and recive some outputs. It's stable too according to the eigenvalues.

Comment: Hard to answer without more details! I suggest you beef up your question with every relevant nook and cranny!

Comment: I will start a new topic there I will explain my problem. I think I have got a good answer in this question. Thank you.